# Custom targets for widget Layout Updates in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I would like help working out how to add a custom container as a 'Layout Update' for a widget..

Currently, I only have the 3 basic options to choose from (Main Content Area, Siderbar Main and Sidebar Additional), but I would like to be able to add widgets to containers that I've created through various default.xml files.

Specifically, I'm trying to include the Recently Viewed widget. I have tried updating `module-reports/etc/widget.xml`, adding an extra  inside the , however that doesn't seem to work..

How can I use a customer container?

Thanks, Luke

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, the custom container that I had created didn't have a label attribute, so Magento was ignoring it as a possible layout destination

Answer (score 2):

**Note: The below has been tested up to Magento 2.2.8**

I had a similar issue and have build a module to do this exact same thing,  but it's in a private repository so I can't give you the link, I can however give you the code; note I've changed the namespace to LD (shorthand for Luke Denton - it can be whatever you want, as long as it's consistent).
Simply upload the below files to **app/code/LD/Reports**

**registration.php**

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'LD_Reports',
    __DIR__
);
```

**etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="LD_Reports" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Reports"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**ets/widget.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widgets xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Widget:etc/widget.xsd">
    <widget id="recently_viewed">
        <containers>
            <container name="my.additional.container">
                <template name="default" value="list_default" />
                <template name="names_only" value="list_names" />
                <template name="images_only" value="list_images" />
            </container>
        </containers>
    </widget>
</widgets>
```

Then in your theme you need a container with a corresponding name and label.

Comment: I can confirm it works for 2.2.8